# Request $request, Response $response em uma classe controller abstrata SLIM FRAMEWORK PHP

Tags: php, slim

Boa tarde a todos.
Estou estudando `Slim Framework 3.12` para PHP, e estou construindo meus controladores para serem chamados nas rotas.
Tenho uma classe **abstrata** chamada Controller.php que uso para inicializar os meus objetos dos controladores que a extendem(usando o extends).

Dessa forma:

```
**<?php**


namespace App\Controllers;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;


abstract class Controller {

    public $request;
    public $response;

    function __construct(Request $request, Response $response) {

        $this->request  = $request;
        $this->response = $response;

    }


}
**?>**
```

Porém não consigo esses $request e $response, dentro dessa classe não estão obtendo o Resquest e Response.
Mas se eu fizer isso nas minhas classes concretas, eu consigo ter acesso:

```
**<?php**

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\Controller;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Slim\Container;

class MyController extends Controller{


    public function index(Request $request, Response $response){
         $request->getMethod();
         $response->getStatusCode();
         echo ("Deu certo");
    }

}
**?>**
```

Como que eu faço para ter acesso na minha classe Abstrata ? 
Pois todo controlador precisa desse Request e Response... .

Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde pessoal,
Consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte, ao invés de colocar como parâmetro no método construtor da classe abstrata Controller.php os: Request $request e Response $response, subsitituí por Container $c , assim:

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Controllers;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

abstract class Controller {

```
public $request;
public $response;

function __construct(\Slim\Container $c) {

    $this->request  = $c->request;
    $this->response = $c->response;

}
```

}
?>

Encontrei essa solução em uma outra página na Web(https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1750#issuecomment-179232639) , mas queria entender porque, pra quê o Slim armazena isso dentro dessa Class Container, queria saber como que essa Classe Container funciona, para entender melhor porque funcionou(Já tenho noção do que é Injeção de Dependência).

Alguém por me esclarecer ?